# Swift Invalid value around character 0

Tags: php, json, swift

i need help with my app login code.
I try to make a Http Request to my local server, a simple login request with mail and password but i've a issue and i don't know how to fix it.

```
@IBAction func clickConnexionBtn(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if(!mailTf.text!.isEmpty && !passwordTf.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        let mail            = mailTf.text!
        let password        = passwordTf.text!

        let param           = String(format: "mail=%@&password=%@", arguments: [mail, password]);
        let url             = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/MoneyManager/login.php")!

        RequestObject.sharedInstance.prepareRequest(param, _url: url, _method: "POST")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(RequestObject.sharedInstance.request)
        { data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                let alertView   = UIAlertController(title: "Error server", message: "Could not connect to server", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                self.showViewController(alertView, sender: self)
            }
            else
            {
                let serverResponse = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Server response: \(serverResponse)")

                do
                {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

                        print(json)
                    }
                } catch let error2 as NSError {
                    print(error2.description)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

So this is the action when i click on the 'connexionButton'.
Unfortunately when i try to Serialize the JSON, i have this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

My PHP code is like:

```php
if($result)
{
    $return = array("Success" => 1, "Message" => "Insert user done", "user_id" => $_SESSION['id'], "api_key" => $_SESSION['api_key']);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Here is the code of my 'print("Server ....")'

```
Server response: Optional(Connexion successfully {"Success":1,"Message":"Insert user done","user_id":"9","api_key":"aa3b0c16fc63efe207be1a7471ac234a"})
```

Its all the data that i want to get and turn into JSON object

I look many subject but no one of them could help me cause most of the people use Alamofire to perform request. 
So please if you have an idea, i listening

Thanks all.

Comment: Please add the output of `print("Server response: \(serverResponse)")` to your question.

Comment: Please add all relevant information *to the question itself*, not to the comments. – And where does "Connexion successfully" come from? That is not JSON and probably the cause for your error.

Comment: @MartinR Ok sorry, i don't know how it really work